# QGIS Cannot show Grid Layer Attribute Table variables as Degrees

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have for the first time opened QGIS 3 on my Mac. I am trying to create a rectangle grid of 50mx50m cells. I then want the centroid of each cell of the grid shown in the attribute table. I can get to this using a scratch layer but the format of the attribute table is shown in metres not decimal degrees. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it looks like you created your grid in EPSG:3857 Pseudo Mercator. Although it uses meters, it is not recommended for analysis or accurate distance measurements. I would suggest a local UTM coordinate reference system such as WGS84 / UTM zone 18N EPSG:32618. You can select this in the algorithm dialog when you create your grid. Click the CRS selector button (shown in the screenshot below) to open CRS selection Dialog.

[image]

You can filter the list by typing (e.g. 'utm zone 18') into the search bar at the top of the dialog (see below). Select the CRS and click OK.

[image]

After creating your grid you can easily add the centroid lat and long values in decimal degrees using the field calculator. Add two new fields e.g. `centroid-lon` and `centroid_lat` (making sure to use type Decimal number (real) and set an appropriate precision) and populate them with the following expressions:

```
x(transform(centroid($geometry), 'EPSG:32618', 'EPSG:4326'))

y(transform(centroid($geometry), 'EPSG:32618', 'EPSG:4326'))
```

[image]

[image]

You should see a result in the attribute table similar to below:

[image]

Comment: What an exceptional response. Thank you! I'll try the recommended now and revert. Thanks again.

Comment: That's worked, thank you so much. Can I ask a couple of questions. Why are the coordinates left, top, right, bottom not in decimal degrees? Also previously I used ```x(centroid($geometry))``` and ```y(centroid($geometry))``` to create the centroid_lat and lon fields and used decimal number real but I got metres...

Comment: @CGarden, you're welcome. The left, top, right and bottom coordinates are in meters because they are added during the execution of the algorithm and are in the CRS in which the grid is  created. That is why we use the `transform` function in the field calculator expression. We transform the centroid geometries to a geographic CRS before extracting their x and y values.

Comment: Ok great. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Ben W, if you wanted to complete the same feat but for the united States excluding Hawai and Alaska at 10km cell size how would you amend the transform function? I'm not sure how you decide on the target and source projections. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @CGarden. I don't do any North American mapping, but if you g00gle 'projected crs for north america', you will find recommended options such as North America Albers Equal Area Conic ESRI:102008 and North America Lambert Conformal Conic ESRI:102009 (I can't tell exactly which you should- you may need to do some trial/research) but they should allow you to create a fairly accurate 10km square grid over contiguous USA. For canvas rendering you probably want to set your project crs to match the grid.

Comment: Then to add the centroid in lat/long to the attribute table you only need to change the source crs (the one that comes first in the expression) for example: x(transform(centroid($geometry), 'ESRI:102008', 'EPSG:4326')).

Comment: Thank you I was using the street map canvas and when amending this to Albers I was getting some error messages on the map. I'll take a look again now. Thank you.

Comment: @CGarden, no you can't change crs of xyz tile or wms layers or reproject them! They are always in epsg:3857 and are for visualisation only! However, basemap layers should reproject on the fly to your project crs.

Comment: Ok thats great thank you. So I just add a basemap of my choosing from online?

Comment: @CGarden, TBH I'm not 100% sure I understand exactly what you are doing and what precisely is the issue you are facing, if any. The following links may be helpful to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8UmmEN5Og4Y  https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/working_with_projections.html  https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html. If necessary you should ask a new question if you need help with a specific problem.

Comment: Thank you again that link is really helpful. I think I have something now that is working. I downloaded a US shape file: https://gadm.org/download_country.html. And created the grid over that and the results from the the transform expressions look more sensible now.

Comment: @CGarden, great! Sounds like you are on the right track :-)

Comment: I did open a new question for this if you want to provide your answer and i'll accept it. [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423616/qgis-unable-to-get-correct-fishnet-cell-centroids-for-united-states) thank you again for all your help.