# QGIS unable to get correct fishnet cell centroids for United States

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I want to create a fishnet grid across the United States with cells sizes of 10km x 10km in QGIS. I then want to pull the coordinates of the centroid of each cell.  I have done a similar thing with Manhattan, NY [previous question and answer.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/418649/qgis-cannot-show-grid-layer-attribute-table-variables-as-degrees)

But with the US I am struggling with the projection type and the transform functions.

Previous transform functions:

```
x(transform(centroid($geometry), 'EPSG:32618', 'EPSG:4326'))

y(transform(centroid($geometry), 'EPSG:32618', 'EPSG:4326'))
```

I have amended these to (and also ESRI:102008) the below, but am not getting coordinates in the US:

```
x(transform(centroid($geometry), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'))

y(transform(centroid($geometry), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'))
```

Comment: The first CRS is your source-CRS, the second your target CRS. Did you take this into account?

Comment: I did not apologies. I'm not sure how you decide to put the two of them together. I'm also not sure how you decide on the best pair for a geographic area. Would you be able to advise please?

Comment: I've had a look online but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to convert it to on the target. Thank you.

Comment: The first CRS you put into the expression is the one your data is in. The second CRS is the one you want the output to be in.